# How to bypass the proxy using java

Tags: java

Here belwo is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;

public class webpageDisplay {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" ); 
        System.getProperties().put( "proxyHost", "I given proxy host" ); 
        System.getProperties().put( "proxyPort", "85" ); 
        URL url=new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection ();
        String encoded = new String
              (Base64.encode(new String("user:pass").getBytes()));
        uc.setRequestProperty("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
        uc.connect();

         //String url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
            JEditorPane editor = new JEditorPane(url);
            editor.setEditable(false);
            JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(editor);
            JFrame f = new JFrame("HTML Demo");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.getContentPane().add(pane);
            f.setSize(800, 600);
            f.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

even though i provided proxy host and userid still iam getting erorr as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: www.yahoo.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:196)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:530)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:480)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:169)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:406)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:541)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:245)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:318)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:790)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:738)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:649)
    at webpageDisplay.main(webpageDisplay.java:26)
```

Can anyone suggest how to resolve the issue or how can i bypass the proxy

Comment: `proxySet` does nothing. It is an urban myth.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the properties `http.proxyHost` and `http.proxyPort` rather than just `proxyHost` and `proxyPort`.

See the following questions for example code:

[How to use an HTTP proxy in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599933/how-to-use-proxy-in-java)

[Connect to a site using proxy code in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035973/connect-to-a-site-using-proxy-code-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have crossed half the bridge.  The way you are passing UID/pwd has to be changed

You also need a java.net.Authenticator object whose static setDefault() method has to be called to setup authentication.  See here for more information

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "132.186.192.234");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "ad001\\userid");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "sect");
```